# Need a workaround on firebase limit of range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on only 1 field

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I need to create a compound query that finds overlapping dates in firebase so I came up with the following:

```
    .where('startDate', '<=', endDate);
    .where('endDate', '>=', startDate);
```

This query would give me overlapping date ranges.  The problem is `firebase` only allows inequality on a single field.  So it won't let me use that query.  Is there a workaround for this?

So if you have a meeting scheduled on 06/15/19 - 06/18/19 you should be able to see others having meetings from 06/17/19 - 07/01/19.  I don't know how to do this if I can only use inequality filters on one date.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only storing dates (and not times), then you can also store each individual date of the meeting in a field of type array.  So, the document with your meeting from June 15 to June 18 would contain an array of four individual dates, probably represented as an integer formatted YYYYMMDD.

Now, if you want to find overlaps, you can perform one query for each date in that range using [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).  Merge the results of the queries on the client, and the results will be all meetings that share at least one day in common with each of the given dates for the original meeting.